# How to find all the react compiled files?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am now working on a react ecommerce website and I have encountered an issue that I forgot to give keys to the lists I rendered. So, I was wondering if there is a way to see one file which contains all the code for that  web app, like in Sass , we write code in different files but we are able to see the massive file that contains all the code that we wrote across multiple files.Even if we can't change that file, it would be nice to see how many lines of code are there. So ,is there a way to do that?

Comment: Not that it's my business, why would you want to examine the transpiled javascript code? It'll likely be nearly unrecognizable as compared to your React JSX component code. What do you hope to gain?

Comment: You can check build folder in your root where you created your project. It should have build/main....js file. Additionally who can see the source in your browser's source code navigator

Comment: Sorry, I might be a bit dumb. I can't find build folder in my react app. I have src and public files but not build file. As for your question , I do really want to see exactly how many lines of code are there in my whole app. Just my interest. Nothing important .

Comment: It likely is minified to a single line that is tens of thousands of characters long. Maybe your browser will "prettify" back to something a little more readable (*whitespace is really for us, not the machines*).

Comment: Depends on how you're building your project. Are you using create-react-app/nextjs/gatsby or a custom build setup?

Comment: I am using a create react app